# Loading images downloaded using cordova.file

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm developing an app using Cordova, but without using Angular since the app needs to be really fast (only pure JS and JQuery).

The app currently needs a big amount of files to work, so instead of putting them as assets and generate a heavy app (more than 1 GB for the .apk), they are downloaded using cordova in a folder inside the `cordova.file.dataDirectory` folder, so they can be referenced somehow the same way in Android and iOS.

The problem is, the images are defined all across the project in this way (jade):

```
img(src="assets/icons/back.svg" width="20" height="20")
```

or (stylus)

```
.main
    background url("assets/images/bg.png")
```

So the question is:

- Is there a way to load all the images in the `codova.file.dataDirectory` without changin the .jade nor .styl files routes definition?
- If this isn't possible, is there a way to change all the .jade and the .styl files in a way that they load the images by default from that folder? (like, replace all the "assets/[whathever]" with "/file/in/cordova/assets/[whatever]")
- If that isn't possible either, which is the best way to load the images from that directory?

Comment: if this files you need are all images you simply can put them in the public html folder and load them by using html. so you don't have to do a workaround.

Comment: @mtizziani they aren't, there are more file types. Also, AFAIK you can't download to the public HTML folder using Cordova since that folder is read only: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file. Also, if I put them in the HTML folder and then I build the app, the .apk weights more than 1GB.

Comment: i load all images via api as base64 and an ajax requests. so i have no problem with the app size. and i only load the image i need to display

Comment: The images are downloaded because the app needs to work offline. The images are downloaded as a zip and then unzipped in the cordova.file.dataDirectory because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing the css of all divs with background-image using JQuery. This is a part of the solution (I obfuscated parts of the code):

```js
${'div'}.each(function(index, div){
  var backgroundImage = $(div).css('background-image')
  $(div).css('background-image', processBackgroundImage(backgroundImage)); 
})

${'img'}.each(function(index, img){
  img.src = cordova.file.dataDirectory + processImageSrc(img);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```